# Oracle update statement error

Tags: oracle, subquery

I need to update a column called `assignment_type_desc` in a table `randm_sampler` with values from source table `clm_snapshot` based on matching `claim_id`. The problem is that there are two records in `clm_snapshot` with NULL `claim_id`'s and different values for `assignment_type_desc`. I do not need these records, hence I included `NOT NULL` condition in the update statement. But the update statement still returns *single row subquery returns more than one row* error.

```
UPDATE RANDM_SAMPLER SET ASSIGNMENT_TYPE_DESC =
  (SELECT DISTINCT A.ASSIGNMENT_TYPE_DESC 
     FROM CLM_SNAPSHOT A, 
          RANDM_SAMPLER B
    WHERE A.CLAIM_ID = B.CLAIM_ID 
      AND A.CURRENT_SNAPSHOT_IND='Y'
      AND A.HO_CONSULTANT_SEQ_NBR = (SELECT MAX(HO_CONSULTANT_SEQ_NBR) 
                                       FROM CLM_SNAPSHOT C 
                                      WHERE A.CLAIM_ID = C.CLAIM_ID 
                                        AND C.CLAIM_ID IS NOT NULL 
                                      GROUP BY CLAIM_ID)
      AND A.CLAIM_ID IS NOT NULL )
```

I am absolutely positive that the duplicates are from the records which have `NULL` values for the `claim_id`. But the `NOT NULL` condition doesn't seem to be effective here. Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 2):

Try to following UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE RANDM_SAMPLER SET ASSIGNMENT_TYPE_DESC =
  (SELECT DISTINCT A.ASSIGNMENT_TYPE_DESC 
     FROM CLM_SNAPSHOT A
    WHERE A.CLAIM_ID = RANDM_SAMPLER.CLAIM_ID 
      AND A.CURRENT_SNAPSHOT_IND='Y'
      AND A.HO_CONSULTANT_SEQ_NBR = (SELECT MAX(HO_CONSULTANT_SEQ_NBR) 
                                       FROM CLM_SNAPSHOT C 
                                      WHERE A.CLAIM_ID = C.CLAIM_ID 
                                        AND C.CLAIM_ID IS NOT NULL 
                                      GROUP BY CLAIM_ID)
      AND A.CLAIM_ID IS NOT NULL )
```

I've removed the JOIN to RANDM_SAMPLER from the subquery and instead added the condition that really important because it makes the link to the table to be updated:

```
A.CLAIM_ID = RANDM_SAMPLER.CLAIM_ID
```

You probably tried the same but adding the table B made things worse. And there was no connection to the outer table.